# Can Hibernate save a new entity while updating a parent object

Tags: hibernate

```
    Collar collar = cat.getCollar();
    if(collar==null) {
        collar = new Collar(cat);
    }

    collar.setStuds(true);

    catDAO.mergeState(cat);
```

This complains that collar is a transient object and that it must be saved before the transaction can be flushed.

I can fix this by doing:

```
    if(collar==null) {
        collar = new Collar(cat);
        catDao.makePersistent();
    }
```

Is this correct? Shouldn't Hibernate take care of persisting my new entity for me?

EDIT: added more detail. I am using Spring MVC version 3.0.5 and Hibernate 3.

```
    class Cat {
        ...
        @OneToOne(mappedBy="cat")
        public Collar getCollar() {
            return collar;
        }
        // etc
    }

    class Collar {
        @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="CAT_ID", nullable = false)
        public Cat getCat() {
            return cat;
        }
        // etc
    }
```

The mergeState() method in my DAO calls `entityManager.merge(cat)` (and `entityManager.flush()` if requested).

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't, unless your `mergeState()` method calls `merge()` and the association between Cat and Collar has a `cascade = MERGE` (or `ALL`) attribute.

Comment: I will edit my question to include mappings. I intend merges to cascade

Comment: But I do have cascade = MERGE on the mapping and my mergeState call does call merge(). I have added more information above. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to persist Cat entity in the line
catDAO.mergeState(cat);

And if you have defined the relation (eg... @OneToMany, etc) between Cat & Collar in the Cat entity.... Then if you persist cat it would also save the child entity collar.

Yes you should have also configure the cascade (ALL, etc)

Comment: I have edited my question to indicate that such mappings do exist but I still have to do it in two steps.

Comment: The cascade should be on `Cat.getCollar()`. Not on `Collar.getCat()`. Since you call merge on Cat and want it to be cascaded to its collar.